# Amazon aws Ec2 instance: Connection refused (by browser). Used to work

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

As the title says, I am getting connection refused by my browser.

Nginx is running with

```
sudo service nginx start
```

This used to start and used to show the nginx start page

My AWS EC2 Security group settings allow connections on port 80, 22, and 443. Please help, thank you

Comment: need more info.  check your error logs and paste out put. /var/log/messages as well regarding nginx service starting?  does ps aux | grep nginx show the service as running? does netstat -nap show the port being bound??  connection refused seems like nginx is not actually starting up properly.

Comment: Did you stop and then start your EC2 instance? And if so, are you using an Elastic IP? If not, then your instance has a new public IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My configuration files did not pass the

sudo nginx -t

test. If you are having this problem, run the command above to see if your configuration files pass that test. I had duplicate error log locations